# Sql Server Profiler cuts off my query text

Tags: sql

I'm running a trace on my SQL Server database using the Sql Profiler tool. The trace is specifically to see the where clause generated by using fluent nhibernate queries. The query text in profiler is being cut off well before the WHERE clause though.

Interesting to note, it's being cut off in the window at the bottom, and not just in the grid. I have also tried exporting to file, but the text is cut off in the output as well.

I can't seem to find any settings where there is a limit I can up.

Can someone outline a way to get the full text of the query when running a profile?

Comment: I have found the profiling utility a bit dodgy in this respect.

Comment: is there an alternative? All I want to do is see the query in full. If i can install another tool to do the same thing I'm all for it

Comment: It seems that this is something to do with the database itself and not the profiler tool. I installed an alternative, non Microsoft profiler and got the same results.